# Problem solving question: knapsack variation with two variables and different total

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to figure out the solution to this problem, which is quite similar to the knapsack problem, but I'm not sure what states I should have or how to memorize them.

You have an electric car which weighs W units and you want to make it go for as long as possible. To do this you must pick from N batteries which also have an energy e, a weight b and a cost c.
The amount of time your car can go for is t = Etotal / Wtotal (the sum of energies of batteries you chose divided by the sum of the weight of the batteries you chose + the weight of the car itself)
Given that you have a budget B, what is the maximum time your car can go for?

Example:

```
INPUT:
N = 10 /number of batteries to choose
B = 1000 /budget
W = 20 /weight of car
#N batteries with numbers e (energy), w (weight), c (cost)
40 40 40
1 1 1
70 30 60
100 20 700
80 50 200
30 1 200
100 100 1
20 1 500
30 20 100
70 50 100

OUTPUT:
3.17073170731707
```

Comment: Can you give an example of inputs and results?

Comment: Yes, I added it

Comment: There's a straightforward DP that needs O(N\*Etotal\*Wtotal) time and O(Etotal\*Wtotal) space -- if that's interesting, let me know. But I'm haunted by the fact that, without any budget constraint, there's a simple O(N\*log N)-time greedy algorithm with a nice proof of correctness -- I feel like there should be a way to incorporate the budget constraint into this nicer algorithm without blowing up the complexity too much, but I can't figure it out!

Comment: I think the straightforward DP would work with the time constraints (NxB < 200000 and all weights and energies are < 1000), so I'm interested in seeing it. Here is the link to the original question https://po.kattis.com/problems/dronare (in Swedish). I don't think there's any greedy algorithm, but if you come up with it, let me know :)

Answer (score 3):

### Straightforward DP algorithm

We can compute the minimum cost f(i, j, k) of a solution that achieves exactly total energy j and total weight k by choosing some subset of the first i batteries. This is given by:

```
f(0, 0, W) = 0
f(0, j!=0, W) = INF
f(0, j, k!=W) = INF
f(i>0, j, k<W) = INF
f(i>0, j, k>=W) = min(f(i-1, j, k), f(i-1, j-E[i], k-W[i]) + C[i])
```

where E[i], W[i] and C[i] are the energy, weight and cost of battery i, respectively. After computing values of this function for all 0 <= i <= N, 0 <= j <= Sum(E[]) and 0 <= k <= W+Sum(W[]), find the maximum of j/k over all 0 <= j <= Sum(E[]) and 0 <= k <= W+Sum(W[]) such that f(N, j, k) <= B.

A direct implementation using a 3D DP table will take time and space O(N*Sum(E[])*(W+Sum(W[]))) time and space. But since the recursion never needs to reach back further than 1 step in the first parameter i, we can make the outermost loop increase i and drop the first dimension from the DP table, overwriting its entries as we go, to drop the space complexity by a factor of N.

The above DP computes minimum costs, but it could be "rotated" to optimise for any of the three variables (minimum cost for given energy and weight, maximum energy for given cost and weight, or minimum weight for given energy and cost). The most efficient approach is to optimise for the variable with the largest range, since the time and space complexity involve the product of the ranges of the remaining two variables.

### Greedy algorithm for unconstrained costs

The following simple O(N*log N)-time, O(N)-space algorithm maximises the distance travelled if there are no cost constraints. I think it's interesting because of the proof of correctness.

1. Sort batteries in decreasing order by energy divided by weight (you could think of this as "energy density").
2. Keep adding batteries from this list until the next battery has energy/weight less than the (total energy)/(total weight) of the batteries (and car) chosen so far.

A key element in proving this correct is the observation that, whenever we combine two multisets of batteries (we can consider the car to be an always-chosen battery with energy level 0), the mean of the resulting multiset is strictly in between the original two means. I'll call this the **"mean-betweenness" lemma**; see Lemma 1 [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/125021/1984) for a proof. Intuitively this means (hehe) that whenever we can add a battery with higher energy density than the multiset of batteries chosen so far, we should -- since the result of combining these two multisets (the new battery is a multiset of size 1) will be strictly in between them, and thus strictly higher than the multiset of batteries chosen so far.

Running the algorithm above will choose a multiset of batteries in which some initial number s of batteries in the sorted list will be chosen, and no other batteries will be chosen. By the mean-betweenness lemma, the algorithm clearly chooses an optimal multiset of solutions among all solutions having this form (that is, among solutions that choose only some initial number of batteries in the list). To establish that it chooses an optimal solution overall, we need to show that no solution that "skips over" one or more batteries in this list and then chooses one or more batteries further down can be better.

Suppose to the contrary that there exists an optimal solution X that skips a battery, and that this solution is strictly better than the solution Y produced by the greedy algorithm. Let i be the first battery that X skips. Thus X and Y share the first i-1 batteries. There are 2 cases:

1. E[i]/W[i] is strictly greater than the energy/weight of X. In this case, by the mean-betweenness lemma, we can add battery i to X to produce a solution that is strictly better than X, contradicting the optimality of X.
2. E[i]/W[i] is less than or equal to the energy/weight of X.

Continuing with case 2, consider the submultiset X' of batteries chosen further down the list by X (by assumption this must contain at least one battery). Because the list is ordered by decreasing energy/weight, these batteries each have energy/weight at most equal to that of battery i (namely, E[i]/W[i]), so by the mean-betweenness lemma their mean energy/weight is also at most equal to E[i]/W[i]. X = (X-X') ∪ X', so by the mean-betweenness lemma, the mean energy/weight of X is strictly between (X-X') and X'. Since the mean energy/weight of X' is less than or equal to the mean energy/weight of X overall, *removing* the batteries in X' from X to leave (X-X') will in the best case (when the means of X and X' are equal) leave the mean unchanged, and otherwise increase it. Either way, we have constructed a new solution (X-X') with mean energy/weight at least as high as X and which consists of the first i-1 batteries in the list -- that is, a solution of the form that the greedy algorithm is known to maximise over.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. I'll try to implement the DP. However I don't think the greedy will work, because it's kind of like fractional knapsack vs 0-1 knapsack. The greedy only works when you can take fractional items, otherwise there are many cases where it goes wrong

Comment: @Marta: Could you give an example where it goes wrong? That would indicate a mistake in the proof. Remember that it only works when the budget constraint is dropped.